# Can I call a function once datatables responsive modal is shown

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to call a function after the modal() is shown, Thanks

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
   responsive: {
      details: {
         display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal()
      }
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can use the following event :

```
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Am not using that. I don't have access to the modal element created by datatable. So, I can't bind it to a function.